# Jquery hide/show elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8xFFH/67/) in javascript but more optimized and with toggle function working !

**My js code :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.details').click(function(e){
        var id= '';
        $('a.details').each(function() {
            id = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#'+id).hide();
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
        id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#'+id).toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: show us some of your html and try to be more explainatory

Comment: @Awea Are you boast that fact? )) what is the essence of the question?

Comment: @Abuld follow the link i have put an example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @silex the essence of the question is how can i make a code more optimized and where the toggle function work

Comment: @abdul, load the fiddle to see the html

Comment: Why are people so aggressive towards people who may or may not grasp jQuery yet?

Comment: I started javascript four months ago sorry for my ignorance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on this WITHOUT changing the html except for adding a t to the ID of the rows

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Rfn8z/

Comments welcome (**especially** if voting down)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.details').each(function() {
    var tr = $("#t"+parseInt($(this).html()));
    var link = this;
    $(this).toggle(
      function(e){tr.show(); $(this).addClass('active');   e.preventDefault();},
      function(e){tr.hide(); $(this).removeClass('active');e.preventDefault();}
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, interesting method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Terrible way of doing things. Instead take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xzpkq/

Maybe you will be inspired to produce better code

Comment: Great that you can be bothered to assist someone who may not have your level of expertise or grasp of great coding yet. Why the superior attitude? Once upon a time you were a noob too. Is it now payback time?

Comment: my intentkons were not to seem superior. sorry if i did. my post was only included to show an alternative.